# Controlling How Documents Stack when Opened

Tags: windows, ms-office, autohotkey, word-2013, window-management

When some programs are opened they automatically cascade (when not opened in full screen), and I want to keep all documents directly on top of each other. I found [this which claims that it is impossible.](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T013374_Controlling_How_Documents_Stack_when_Opened.html)

I know that it can be done by having AutoHotkey watch if newly opened windows are not touching a border and moving it to the closest border, or to watch the position of the window when it is activated. Does anyone know of a good way to solve this using e.g. AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I have found so far is using DisplayFusion, which solves this using the setting 
["window location"](https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/WindowLocation/). Here’s [a short guide](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/position-and-combination-of-programs/?ID=63475317-e0c9-4490-9e6d-702bccc911d1). I also found that [there is a way to script it using the same program](https://www.displayfusion.com/ScriptedFunctions/View/?ID=ecd0626e-800f-40b7-8674-6e3aaa0d25e9).